# angular $http.get not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

So i'm testing $http.get in angular to grab a json file and i've used this code:

```
$scope.classes =   $http.get('coursedata.json')
    .success(function (result){
           $scope.classes = result; a
      console.log(result);
             })
  .error(function(data,status){
  console.log(status);
  } );
```

but it wasn't working, its showing a successful get but in my angular html page it is not accessing the data.

my html is something like:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="oflClassCtrl">
 <tr ng-repeat = "selectedClass in classes | filter:searchTxt">
        <td><a  ng-click="clickToOpen($index)">{{selectedClass.class}}</a></td>
```

the page renders correctly when i have the data in the controller but for some reason something is not working when i try to use the get request and $http service.

also im running a local host with php on xampp apache server so the $http should work right?

Comment: what errors do you get? Is the json valid? If in doubt run it through a validator

Comment: what if you type the http address of your JSON file in your browser. what do you see?

Comment: the json was not correct and was missing commas. please create an answer for this so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.classes` likely has invalid assigned to it, hence the successful `$http.get` but dysfunctional `ng-repeat` in your markup. Examining your JSON format should fix the issue

**[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)** - one of the many quick online tools you can use

Answer (score 0):

try producing a function at your scope, and set data there:

```
$scope.setData = function( data ) {
....
```

I think this is something with watch context.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function in the scope variable:

```
$scope.classes =  function() {
$http.get('coursedata.json')
    .success(function (result){
           $scope.classes = result; a
      console.log(result);
             })
  .error(function(data,status){
  console.log(status);
  } );
}
```

Considering you want to call it or the function to be triggered